# What is difference between lb://serviceId and http://serviceId:port?

Tags: spring-boot, ssl-certificate, openshift, spring-cloud-gateway, sslhandshakeexception

I'm trying to deploy spring-cloud-gateway on openshift using docker. When I give routing URL expression as "https://'+serviceId+':'+getPort()" it works fine. but when I give url-expression as lb://'+serviceId getting below error while routing request to service:

```
avax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No subject alternative names matching IP address 10.10.10.1 found
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
```

Comment: I don't know _spring-cloud-gateway_ but I assume `lb` would mean **load balancing** in the context of cloud services. And having an IP (`10.10.10.1`) for a `serviceId` does not look right, and I would assume that you need to use the name of the service indeed. But all of that is just a wild guess.

Comment: Ip is being resolved by gateway it self, I have not specified Ip explicitly. I have given pattern only as 


url-expression: "'lb://'+serviceId"

Comment: As I said I have no knowledge about **spring-cloud-gateway**. The error message says that Java tries to do an SSL connection to `10.10.10.1` and that the certificate provided by the (HTTPS?) server running on `10.10.10.1` does not contain `10.10.10.1` in the alternative name list so the certificate is considered invalid for the IP. Changing `https://'+serviceId+':'+getPort()` to `'lb://'+serviceId` resulting in that error indicates to me, that the service is now referenced by IP while it probably should be reference by name.

Comment: it should use serivce name when lb://serviceId like what it  is doing when used https://serviceId to connect to a service within same cluster. Underline kubernetes will be able to identify the service within same cluster and route the request

Comment: Yes but I suspect that `serviceId` for some reason contains the IP instead of the service name.

Comment: After doing some research found that spring-cloud-gateway uses ribbon for load balancing by default, which does the load balancing in POD mode not in service mode, which routes the requests to service by identifying the IP of a pod. Need to disable ribbon load balancing by setting 
spring:
  cloud:
    loadbalancer:
      ribbon:
        enabled: false

Answer (score 2):

**lb://serviceId** - refers to an internal micro-service in general and gateway needs to resolves its IP Address and the required instance (for load balancing) with the help of service discovery system (like eureka)

**http://serviceUrl:port** - refers to an external or internal service which is accessible using direct URL - system does not need to query and resolve its name from eureka or any service discovery system. NOTE: In this case the load balancing (using eureka) wont work if you are referring your internal service.

The Error you have posted is clearly related to SSL Handshake, but I guess you have not shared the complete error stack. The error stack must have more information to resolve your issue